# Unit testing text to html throwing assertion error because of extra characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have this function:

```
def text_to_html(text):
    """
    Convert text into HTML
    Args:
        text (): text to convert

    Returns:
        HTML string
    """
    html = "<p>" + text.replace("\n", "<br>") + "</p>"
    return html
```

I'm trying to create a unit test for this function like this.

```
class TestDebtModules(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_html(self):
        string = """
        THIS
        IS A TEST
        STRING
        """
        string_input = text_to_html(string)
        string_output = r'<p><br>THIS <br>IS A TEST <br>STRING<br></p>'
        self.assertEqual(string_input, string_output)
```

However. it's throwing an assertion error because it's adding extra characters in my string. Is this a known bug or is it me doing something wrong? (Hopefully the latter). If it happens to be the former, is there any workaround for this?

```
Expected :<p><br>        THIS<br>        IS A TEST<br>        STRING<br>        </p>
Actual   :<p><br>THIS <br>IS A TEST <br>STRING<br></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is in `"""` a multiline string, which includes the spaces and newlines.

To remove those spaces, consider using a string with implicit newlines instead, like below:

```py
string = "THIS\nIS A TEST\nSTRING\n"
```

or

```py
string = ("THIS\n"
          "IS A TEST\n"
          "STRING\n")
```

If you still wanted to use it in the same way, you could remove the spaces as below:

```
string = """
         THIS
         IS A TEST
         STRING
         """
string = string.replace(" ", "")
```

However, this would also remove the spaces between words

Comment: Thanks. But if I run this in a normal script print(repr(string)), no strange characters are shown. Is there any way I could visualize them?